# Автоматическое добавление пакетов в список import

Tags: flash, ide

Привет. Скажите, пожалуйста, кто знает возможно ли, чтоб `Adobe Flash Professional` сам определил какие пакеты включить, и добавил их в список `import` (как в Eclipse).

Спасибо.

Comment: Полностью автоматически вряд ли какой IDE вставляет импорты.
Как вариант в помощь:
- создавать Pro AS3 проект во Flash Builder, он позволяет писать код для Flash CS5 проекта в builder (eclipse)
- на неизвестном классе нажать Ctrl+1, выдаст варианты решения проблемы, там будет и вариант с импортом

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе это вариант.

Comment: Еще можете попробовать [IDEA](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/Flash_Platform/111315/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это возможно, если вы код писать будете, а не вставлять в поле, тогда автоматически в самом верху появятся строки import.*

[image]

Comment: Я сам пишу, но он ничего не вставляет. Подсказки на методы дает, а вот именно импорта нету, а мне крайне важно. Должен сказать очень неудобный редактор, легче наверно в блокноте писать. А горячая клавиша есть, как например ctrl+shift+o в Эклипсе (которому кстати не важно, вставил или сам написал, кликаешь рядом на эррор и он добавит пакет если имеется)?

Comment: Об этом ничего сказать не могу, сам не так сильно интересуюсь флеш, и редактор этот не изучал, но возможно, пакеты вам попросту не нужны, редактор умный, попробуйте мой код дублировать у себя, что получится?

Comment: ничего не получится, я пробывал

Comment: жалко, у вас какая версия?

Comment: На CS3 и CS5 тоже пробовал. Все желание отбивает. Совсем забыл сказать Вам большое спасибо, что тратите время !

Comment: Незачто, не знаю только как вам помочь(

Comment: Переустановил CS5 и все в порядке. Просто видимо не так село.